# Implementing delivery report in Kannel

Tags: php, mysql, kannel

I've configured Kannel in Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS. I am able to push the messages for now but I am yet to figure out how to implement the delivery report. For this I've the following kannel configuration where I've defined storage type and mysql-connection group and connection properties to mysql.

```
include = "/etc/kannel/modems.conf"

group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = 12345
admin-deny-ip = “*.*.*.*”
admin-allow-ip = “127.0.0.1″
box-deny-ip = “*.*.*.*”
box-allow-ip = “127.0.0.1″
log-file = /var/log/kannel/bearerbox.log
log-level = 0
dlr-storage = mysql

group = smsc
smsc = at
smsc-id = GSM
my-number = xxxxxxxxxxxx
modemtype = auto
device = /dev/ttyUSB0

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender =13013
log-file = /var/log/kannel/smsbox.log
log-level = 0

group = smsbox-route
smsbox-id = smsbox
smsc-id = GSM

group = sendsms-user
username = user
password = user
concatenation= true
max-messages = 10
user-deny-ip = “*.*.*.*”
user-allow-ip = “127.0.0.1;”
dlr-url = "http://127.0.0.1/dlr.php"

group = sms-service
keyword = default
catch-all = yes
accepted-smsc = usb1-modem
max-messages = 0
get-url = http://localhost/sms?phone=%p&text=%a

group = mysql-connection
id = mydlr
host = localhost
port = 3306
username = root
password = 00000
database = dlr
max-connections = 1

group = dlr-db
id = mydlr
table = dlr
field-smsc = smsc
field-timestamp = ts
field-destination = destination
field-source = source
field-service = service
field-url = url
field-mask = mask
field-status = status
field-boxc-id = boxc
```

Now my question is:

1. How to write to the database table dlr? Is it done by kannel or we've to do it through a script?

I tried passing the dlr-mask and dlr-url in the sendsms url but nothing happens.

```
http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=user&password=user&to=xxxxxxxx&text=hello&dlr-mask=31&dlr-url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fdlr.php%3FmyId%3D123456%26type%3D%25d
```

Above all, I don't understand how the "**id**" of the message is handled. As per my understanding I feel that kannel should insert every send information to the database and then the status of the message should be returned according to the id in the database. But in the table there is no such field as *id*.

I am stuck for couple of days with this issue as the Userguide do not have exhaustive directions nor the kannel forums have any good threads on this. Kindly, enlighten me with detailed procedure to implement the delivery report.

Comment: you will have to create table dlr manually. kannel only creates send_sms and sent_sms automatically

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own script(dlr.php) to handle the DLR answer and save the status, about the id you can generate it using timestamp or autoincrement.
Finally your send sms request should look something like this

```
 $dlrURL="http://www.xxxxx.com:/dlr.php?dlr=%d&answer=%A&to=%p&ts=%T&smsID=$yourOwnID";

    /* Build Kannel Request */
    $request  = "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?";
    $request .= "smsc="      ."smppgw1";
    $request .= "&username=" ."someuser";
    $request .= "&password=" ."somepass";
    $request .= "&from="     .$fromNumber;
    $request .= "&to="       .trim($somenumber);
    $request .= "&text="     .urlencode($in_msg);
    $request .= "&dlr-mask=31&dlr-url="     .urlencode($dlrURL);
```

Regards
GOrki

Answer (score 0):

The most stable method to get and store the DLR reorts and MO,MT report to database is to use an addition addon box called SQLBOX, you can also send SMS by inserting it into SQLBOX table.You can find the the source code in the addon directory under kannel main project